# connecting to WAMP SQL database using PHP object

Tags: php, database, wamp

I want to call a php file in the WAMP server from my android app. The php file is then expected to connect to the WAMP sql database. I have written the following code. I need the structure as below because of the format of the data im planning to upload.

So now the problem is as soon as I make a ConfigGraphsDAO object in uploadRequest method, the fileId is returning null. but if i comment that line the fileId is return as 2. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong please. Thanks  a lot

The php file called from my app is called UploadController.php and its as follows

```
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'DAO.php';
$fileId=1;
class UploadController {
    private static function uploadRequest() {
       global $config;
       $configGraphDAO = new ConfigGraphsDAO();
       $fileName = (isset($_POST[self::$PARAM_FILE_NAME])) ? $_POST[self::$PARAM_FILE_NAME] : null;
       $GLOBALS['fileId']=$GLOBALS['fileId']+1;         
       echo self::$PARAM_FILE_ID . "=" . $GLOBALS['fileId'];
    }
}
```

ConfigGraphsDAO.php is as below.

```
class ConfigGraphsDAO extends DAO{
//I plan to do something here. But right now its all empty
}
```

DAO.php is as follows

```
abstract class DAO {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->connect();
  }

  private function connect() {
    global $config;
    $this->con = mysql_connect($config["DB_HOST"], $config["DB_USER"], $config["DB_PASSWORD"],$config["DB_NAME"] );
    if (!$this->con) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to connect to database." . mysql_error());
    }
}
}
```

config.php is as follows.

```
$config = array();
$config["DB_HOST"] = "localhost"; //"http://172.26.191.215"; //"localhost"; //
$config["DB_NAME"] = "ocean";
$config["DB_USER"] = "root";
$config["DB_PASSWORD"] = "";
$config["UPLOAD_DIR"] = "context_repo";
$config["DASH_SERVER_ADDR"] = "http://172.26.191.215/ocean";
```

Comment: Where is `$PARAM_FILE_NAME` defined?

Comment: I think you need to read the manual on the subject of [Abstract classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) Mainly this `Classes defined as abstract may not be instantiated`. And this `When inheriting from an abstract class, all methods marked abstract in the parent's class declaration must be defined by the child;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

include ConfigGraphsDAO.php also in the required files list

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem. So like in java when we are using another php file is it necessary to put it like "require_once 'ConfigGraphsDAO.php';" at the beginning.